# How to equalize the right and left hand side of this equation in induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

so im currently doing an induction problem, and I'm at the stage where I have to prove the K+1, but I'm stuck on how to equalize the left and right hand side of this equation. can anyone help me with solving this?
thanks in advance

$$\frac{(k-1)(3k+2)k(k+2)+4k(k+1)}{4k(k+1)k(k+2)}=\frac{k(3k+5)}{(4k+4)(k+2)}$$

Comment: This is hard to read.  Is $k$ meant to be the same as $K$?  Is there meant to be a difference between $ab$ and $a.b$?

Comment: I attempted to reformat your post.  I guessed that $k=K$.  Please check to confirm that I didn't introduce any errors.  I had no guess what you meant by $k.2$ on the left so I left that as it was.  Maybe you meant $k^2$?  Maybe $2k$?  Something else?

Comment: In any case, note that $4(k+1)=4k+4$ so some cancellation is immediate. Also note that the left numerator is divisible by $k$ as is the left denominator. Beyond that, expand and recombine the numerator on the left.

Comment: thank you so much for the edit, take k(k.2) on the left hand side is supposed to be k(k+2)  sorry about the typo, I tried taking a pict of it and upload it here, but it is still not visible for some reason.

Comment: Well, it doesn't look like you have tried anything.  Post edit, it is clear that the left denominator has terms like $(4k+4)(k+2)$ which instantly cancels the right denominator.  Now do what I suggested regarding the left numerator.